# No sound on Macbook Air

Tags: audio, usb, appletv, airplay, headphones

Yesterday I tried to use Apple TV, it connected but I realised that I don't have Airplay so I disconnected the Apple TV. I then transfered some files using a USB and after that I have no sound on Mac. I get a stop sign when trying to change volume. There is no output device listed. I have restarted many times, tried using the headphone port and USB headphones. USB headphones work, but the headphone port for regular headphones wont work at all. I can get sound through USB headphones or if I pair Mac with Apple TV, we get sound on our tv but no picture. I just want sound back on my Mac.

Please can anyone offer any advice or solution?

Comment: What do you show listed for output devices in **System Preferences > Sound** Output tab?

Comment: The list is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discussion in [Apple Support Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4518120) may shed some light.  First, check to see that **Mute** is not checked.  You may need to [reset the system PRAM](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761?locale=en_US).  Here are the steps: [(From Apple Support)](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761?locale=en_US)

> If your Mac doesn’t seem to be remembering your speaker volume,
>   display resolution, or the disk it should be using during startup, you
>   may need to reset your computer’s PRAM.
>
> Resetting PRAM may change some system settings and preferences. Use
>   System Preferences to restore your settings.
>
> Important:   To print these instructions, click the Share button  in
>   the Help window, then choose Print. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
>
> Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Option, Command (⌘), P, and
>   R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
>
> Turn on your Mac.
>
> Immediately press and hold the Option-Command-P-R keys. You must press
>   this key combination before the gray screen appears.
>
> Continue holding the keys down until your Mac restarts, and you hear
>   the startup sound for the second time.
>
> Release the keys.
>
> After resetting your computer’s PRAM, you may need to update your
>   speaker volume, display resolution, and startup disk preferences. For
>   more information about PRAM, see the Apple Support article About NVRAM
>   and PRAM.

If you are nervous about doing so, if you have an Apple Store close by, you may wish to make an appointment with the Genius Bar.

[image]

Comment: Great! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced it today.. my sounds does'nt work actually it turns out totally  gray I can't even press the sound mode  whether higher or lower. Anyway, I took others advice;  all you need is to do is

1. Turn off your macbook then start it again while pressing Option+Command+P+R (at the same time)
2. You need to press it  for few minutes, I guess until you will hear a sounds as it open.. then that's it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!.  Please refrain from adding comments in an Answer even if it's just to say that another answer worked for you.  The preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to [your reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).  Please see the [About] page and also [answer]. - From Review